# How to see all undelivered mails in Apache James

Tags: james

I am facing an issue with Apache James.
I see mails are showing as Successfully Spooled but its not going out of the system/ not getting delivered. I checked the destination and that is fine.

Is there any cli or way using which I can track mails which are stuck in James queue?
And if they are stuck how do I resend them?